# Is it incorrect to use multiple 'split' filters down the FFmpeg's filter_complex tree?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it better to use the split filter only once per input (say once per [0:v]) or is it OK to split "down the line" again, like below?

```
[0:v]split=2[0v_1][0v_2];
[0v_1]<do sth here>[result1];
[0v_2]<do sth here>[result2];
[result1]split=2[result1_1][result1_2];
[result1_1]<do some more here>[final_result_1];
[result1_2]<and also something here>[final_result_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

That example is fine. You perform only one split per input. `0:v` and `result1` are not the same stream, since `result1` is the outcome of some processing upon `0:v`.